# VM5111:1249 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

Hello i have this error and cannot seem to understand it. I am learning google pie charts and was able to use the sample provided by google api. But now i intend to hover the div and make the piechart explode. when the mouse leaves the div it returns to a normal piechart. But having an error when i hover over the div.
Below is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
            ['Work',     11],
            ['Eat',      2],
            ['Commute',  2],
            ['Watch TV', 2],
            ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);
      
        var options = {
            title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };
      
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
      
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    
    
    var div1 = document.getElementById('piechart');
    
    $(div1).mouseover(function(){
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);
    });

    function drawChart1() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
            ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
            ['Dogri', 2.3], ['Gujarati', 46], ['Hindi', 300],
            ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
            ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
            ['Marathi', 72], ['Nepali', 2.9], ['Oriya', 33],
            ['Punjabi', 29], ['Sanskrit', 0.01], ['Santhali', 6.5],
            ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
        ]);
      
        var options = {
            title: 'Indian Language Use',
            legend: 'none',
            pieSliceText: 'label',
            slices: {  4: {offset: 0.2},
                      12: {offset: 0.3},
                      14: {offset: 0.4},
                      15: {offset: 0.5},
            },
        };
      
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="pie_chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: your code is working.

Comment: @NinaScholz how do i make it return back to the previous piechart when the mouse leaves the div. That is i want it to only change when mouse is on the div and when it leaves returns to original piechart

Comment: i think, it should be something with mouseout: `$(div1).mouseout(function(){
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    });`

Comment: @WhiteHat i used mouseout but didn't work. And how could i add different animations.

Comment: @WhiteHat could you please show me an example

Comment: sorry, my mistake, pie charts don't appear to [support animation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#supported-modifications)...

Answer (score 0):

here's an example using both `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the same chart

using full page view, it doesn't appear to work very smoothly, doesn't always capture `mouseout`...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
    title: 'My Daily Activities',
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Language', 'Speakers (in millions)'],
    ['Assamese', 13], ['Bengali', 83], ['Bodo', 1.4],
    ['Dogri', 2.3], ['Gujarati', 46], ['Hindi', 300],
    ['Kannada', 38], ['Kashmiri', 5.5], ['Konkani', 5],
    ['Maithili', 20], ['Malayalam', 33], ['Manipuri', 1.5],
    ['Marathi', 72], ['Nepali', 2.9], ['Oriya', 33],
    ['Punjabi', 29], ['Sanskrit', 0.01], ['Santhali', 6.5],
    ['Sindhi', 2.5], ['Tamil', 61], ['Telugu', 74], ['Urdu', 52]
  ]);

  var options1 = {
    backgroundColor: 'cyan',
    title: 'Indian Language Use',
    legend: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'label',
    slices: {
      4: {offset: 0.2},
      12: {offset: 0.3},
      14: {offset: 0.4},
      15: {offset: 0.5},
    },
  };

  var div1 = document.getElementById('piechart');
  var div2 = document.getElementById('msg');
  $(div1).mouseover(function(){
    div2.innerHTML = 'over'
    chart.draw(data1, options1);
  });
  $(div1).mouseout(function(){
    div2.innerHTML = 'out'
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
 
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(div1);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```